# How to pull or clone by tag name or commit signature via git

Tags: git

1. We can use git ls-remote to get tag info, I want to know how to checkout the repo with a tag name `v2.6.11` or the hash like `5dc01c595e6c6ec9ccda4f6f69c131c0dd945f8c`
2. What the difference between `refs/tags/v2.6.11` and `refs/tags/v2.6.11^{}`?

   $ git ls-remote git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
   14186fea0cb06bc43181ce239efe0df6f1af260a        HEAD
   14186fea0cb06bc43181ce239efe0df6f1af260a        refs/heads/master
   5dc01c595e6c6ec9ccda4f6f69c131c0dd945f8c        refs/tags/v2.6.11
   c39ae07f393806ccf406ef966e9a15afc43cc36a        refs/tags/v2.6.11^{}
   5dc01c595e6c6ec9ccda4f6f69c131c0dd945f8c        refs/tags/v2.6.11-tree
   c39ae07f393806ccf406ef966e9a15afc43cc36a        refs/tags/v2.6.11-tree^{}
   26791a8bcf0e6d33f43aef7682bdb555236d56de        refs/tags/v2.6.12
   9ee1c939d1cb936b1f98e8d81aeffab57bae46ab        refs/tags/v2.6.12^{}
   9e734775f7c22d2f89943ad6c745571f1930105f        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc2
   1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc2^{}
   0397236d43e48e821cce5bbe6a80a1a56bb7cc3a        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc3
   a2755a80f40e5794ddc20e00f781af9d6320fafb        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc3^{}
   ebb5573ea8beaf000d4833735f3e53acb9af844c        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc4
   88d7bd8cb9eb8d64bf7997600b0d64f7834047c5        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc4^{}
   06f6d9e2f140466eeb41e494e14167f90210f89d        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc5
   2a24ab628aa7b190be32f63dfb6d96f3fb61580a        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc5^{}
   701d7ecec3e0c6b4ab9bb824fd2b34be4da63b7e        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc6
   7cef5677ef3a8084f2588ce0a129dc95d65161f6        refs/tags/v2.6.12-rc6^{}
   0da688d20078783b23f99b232b272b027d6c3f59        refs/tags/v2.6.13
   02b3e4e2d71b6058ec11cc01c72ac651eb3ded2b        refs/tags/v2.6.13^{}
   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply checkout the SAH-1 or the tag name directly.

for example:

```
git checkout v2.6.12-rc4 

or:

git checkout ebb5573ea8beaf000d4833735f3e53acb9af844c
```

are equivalens